# Log normal price simulation

Tags: simulations, distribution, normal-distribution, lognormal, log-returns

I'm trying to figure out a spreadsheet I have which simulates 50000 returns in excel using the following function:

```
LOGNORM.INV(RAND(),0,0.35)-1
```

**Question:**

How does adding a minus 1 to the end of this formula convert what is essentially a log normally distributed price to a normally distributed return?

Comment: Subtracting one doesn't convert it to a normally distributed return.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, adding a minus 1 does not transform a log normal variable into an normal distributed variable.
The only thing that I can think of which make sense is the log normal represents a price ratio $\frac{P_t}{P_0}$ (for instance if the price process is a geometric browninan motion). In this case adding -1 does transform price ratio into arithmetic return $R_t=\frac{P_t - P_0}{P_0} =\frac{P_t}{P_0}-1$. if you make the assumption that $P_0=1$, then indeed $R_t=P_t-1$. But in any case, the return does not follow normal law.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, that code generates draws from a [*shifted lognormal distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

Define $R_t = \frac{P_t + D_t}{P_{t-1}} - 1$ as the *return* from $t-1$ to $t$.

Define $r_t = \log \left( 1 + R_t \right)$ as the *log return* from $t-1$ to $t$. (Note if $D_t=0$ then $r_t = \log P_t - \log P_{t-1}$.)

Your code above generates *returns* where the corresponding *log return* follows the normal distribution.

As a practical matter, the [linear approximation of $f(x) = \log(1+x)$ around $x=0$ is given by $x$,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244199/why-is-it-that-natural-log-changes-are-percentage-changes-what-is-about-logs-th/244237#244237) hence for $r_t$ near zero, we have $r_t \approx R_t$. If a return is .02, the log return is .0198. (Of course, this breaks down the farther one is from zero.)